# Can use specific button to vibrate another one? How?

Tags: java, android, vibration, android-vibration

I've created an alarm for each event in the calendar. Now I'm thinking about a new method to stop the alarm by the user in a new way :)
and that way is:

The user has to hold down two fingers (thumb and index) for 5 seconds until the button that the thumb is on vibrates!! I know I'm thinking a silly thing but I need to know how to do it please.

> *I know how to create a method of vibration by `OnClicklistener` or `onTouchlistener`*

but what I want exactly is: if the user clicks on the two buttons, one of them for thumb and the other for index for 5 seconds then the button of the thumb vibrates alone so the user will feel his thumb vibrating :) then he will know that the alert will stop forever!

> (the type of vibration looks like what in this app :
>   [real_calc_app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.nickfines.RealCalc&hl=en) )

Comment: It sounds like you want specific locations on the screen to vibrate separately and AFAIK phones/tablets generally have one piece of vibrating equipment which is not specific to any location on-screen.

Comment: yes i know that, but how to do it ?

Comment: buttons do not vibrate

Comment: @Blackbelt : No , they can

Comment: Buttons does not vibrate. Device has a vibrator function and is like a boolean: ON or OFF . Not localization is possible. C'mon ... What you talking about?

Comment: I swear there is a method !!!

Comment: You can make the button view "vibrate" by changing its x and y positions on the screen, but you cannot have selective haptic feedback for only a portion of the screen. That doesn't make any sense given the set of physics law that govern the universe we live in.

Comment: Are you talking about physical buttons or views? And do you mean "wiggle" by vibrate or physical vibration?

Comment: may be it's not vibrating but it's like vibration i don't know @jyoon

Comment: You need to give us an example! We can't understand!

Comment: @jyoon : it looks like a small vibration

Comment: That app shows a simple vibration, which you can implement with roarster's method. Give it a try, maybe use 100 instead of 500 to make it more like that app you linked to.

Comment: @Splatters: i don't know how to do it, please give me a tutorial or something help me or example by answering this question

Comment: it vibrates by only the button you pressed, i put my finger on other button at the same time and i didn't feel any vibration

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make the device vibrate then you need to add the vibrate permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

and the code to vibrate is:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(500);
```

but like I commented, it's not specific to any particular location on the screen - It'll vibrate the entire device. There's no way to vibrate specific locations.

Comment: i know the code you wrote as i wrote in my question but i want for specific location , and i believed that there is a method to do that

Comment: [This is how a smartphone vibrator works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWgN20Xx-5A).

Comment: thanks for you :) but i still believe in what I'm thinking of !! so did you know a method to make the experts here to see my question ??!!

Comment: Go throw some money at [Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/) then and have them tell you you're wrong.

Comment: if i see you an app did it ?!!

Comment: If you can show me an app that's done it, then go ahead, send me the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78713/discussion-between-roarster-and-hani-kamal).